# Turn all windows transparent in Mavericks

Tags: macos, accessibility

I have been looking around for over an hour now trying to find some way to make all my windows somewhat transparent / translucent ...

I found the app Afloat, however that app doesn't work with all other applications, only some

Any ideas on how I can turn all my windows semi-transparent in OS X Mavericks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the window colors in Finder itself. However, there are finger alternatives that can do this. Try Pathfinder by [CocoaTech](http://cocoatech.com/pathfinder/). I believe it has the option to make Finder windows transparent.

Comment: Just "Finder" windows?

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you open a new finder window and go into the preferences you can edit the color of the window background. From that you can then modify the alpha channel to add transparency :)

Comment: This only works for finder though correct?

Comment: Sorry I misread the question. So you want the main bar (where the close,min,max buttons are located) to be translucent?

Comment: I want the same thing you described for the finder window, but for all of my windows, 'Chrome;PhpStorm;Spotify;Notes;etc...

Comment: I don't believe Mavericks offers this functionality natively.

Comment: It does not. For what it's worth, I'm installing Ubuntu because I'm fed up with the limitations of OS X.

Answer (score 0):

NOT AN ANSWER 
Try reverse engineering this
https://www.howtogeek.com/199201/how-to-disable-window-transparency-in-os-x-yosemite/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! We try to refrain from posting link-only answers, as they decrease readability and are susceptible to link rot. Could you please post any relevant info to the body of your post?